# filectime() [function.filectime]: stat failed for

Tags: php, file

i m having this problem in Codeigniter based applicaition.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: filectime() [function.filectime]: stat failed for cache/6485224e8a2979278bc2725ce316d891717dbfad.php

Filename: libraries/Simple_cache.php

Line Number: 57
```

Answer (score 0):

- Probably permission denied?
- [Aren't you calling it without arguments?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php#102023)

Comment: Nope, i am calling with Arguments with the file path. But its showing me this waringin. Again i have putted the file permission to 0777. but still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in my searching for an answer:

> If PHP's integer type is only 32 bits on your system, filemtime() will
>   fail on files over 2GB with the warning "stat failed". All
>   stat()-related commands will exhibit the same behavior.
>
> As a workaround, you can call the system's stat command to get the
>   modification time of a file:
>
> On FreeBSD: $mtime = exec ('stat -f %m '. escapeshellarg ($path));
>
> On Linux: $mtime = exec ('stat -c %Y '. escapeshellarg ($path));

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10379026-RESOLVED-filectime-stat-failed-workaround

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party however noticed from your error log that you are using Simple Cache library.

Your issue might be that the cache is create as a .cache file but the line that checks it is using a .php extension.

See:

```
$file_expires = file_exists(APPPATH.'cache/'.$key.'.cache') ? filectime(APPPATH.'cache/'.$key.'.php')+$this->expire_after : (time() - 10);
```

Should be:

```
$file_expires = file_exists(APPPATH.'cache/'.$key.'.cache') ? filectime(APPPATH.'cache/'.$key.'.cache')+$this->expire_after : (time() - 10);
```

Just incase anyone else stumbles upon this